# Insert a value in a not identity primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm working with SQL SERVER 2012, C#, .NET Framework 4.0 and Entity Framework Code First 6.1.3.

I have generated this table with SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PRODUCTS]
(
    [PRODUCT_ID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [PRODUCT_CODE] NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    [DESCRIPTION] NVARCHAR(50) NULL, 
    [LAW] TINYINT NOT NULL 
)
```

To access it with EF I have this class:

```
public class PRODUCTS
{
    public int PRODUCT_ID { get; set; }
    public string PRODUCT_CODE { get; set; }
    public string DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
    public byte LAW { get; set; }
}
```

With this configuration:

```
class PRODUCTSConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<PRODUCTS>
{
    public PRODUCTSConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(p => p.PRODUCT_ID);

        Property(p => p.PRODUCT_CODE)
            .HasMaxLength(20)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(p => p.DESCRIPTION)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsOptional();

        Property(p => p.LAW)
            .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

But when I try to insert a new row in this table using Entity Framework I get an exception on `dbContext.SaveChanges();` saying that `PRODUCT_ID` cannot be null:

> You can not insert the value NULL in the 'PRODUCT_ID' column, PRODUCTS
>   table. The column does not allow NULL values. INSERT.Se error ended
>   instruction.

I insert a new product I do this:

```
PRODUCTS dataProduct = new PRODUCTS()
{
    PRODUCT_ID = product.Id,
    PRODUCT_CODE = product.ProductCode,
    LAW = product.Law,
    DESCRIPTION = product.Description
};

dbContext.Add(dataProduct);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

But I have debugged and `PRODUCT_ID` has a value.

Do I need to do something else to insert that value on `PRODUCT_ID` column?

By the way, I need to insert a value in `PRODUCT_ID` column, I can't use IDENTITY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really can't see how the ID can be null, given that it's declared as an `int` and not, say, `int?`. If there's an object instance, then there must be a value -- probably a `0` if something's gone wrong with the initialisation of the object.

The model-building code looks right, but there's a quirk in the code you quote for adding the item. I would expect something like

```
dbContext.Products.Add(dataProduct);
```

using a DbSet called `Products`, rather than

```
dbContext.Add(dataProduct);
```

I don't se how that would make a difference but would be interested to know whether that's just a typo, or is part of the issue.

Does it work if you add the entry direct to the context, like this?

```
dbContext.Entry(newStudent).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider, instead of having a straight integer ID field, make that an autonumber ([IDENTITY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186775.aspx)) column. If you make it IDENTITY, you can leave the product.Id = 0 and EF will generate it automatically. After `dbContext.SaveChanges` has been called, product.PRODUCT_ID will have been set for you, if you need to ID of the created object.

Comment: Sorry, but this not answer my question. I'm asking why if I have set a value on `PRODUCT_ID` EF throw an exception saying that the column value is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

[Table("TestTable")]
public class TestTable
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string descr { get; set; }
}
```